# New redesign removes spaces between user, vote count, question & answer and vote count, and is as a result ugly

Tags: bug, design

Some time in the last few weeks ugly things happened to the site pages.

[image: No spaces on question answer views]

No spaces Between 1&Vote, 2&Answers, 2K&Views.

[image: space only before time]

No spaces between userhandle, votes, and  asked, answered etc. Yet there's still a space before time.

Just <bleepin'> fugly. What happens when you *fix* stuff that *ain't broken.* You actually break things. itishardertoreadstufflikethis

emily dickenson's ghost also took away all capitals, (*i.e.* for votes, etc.)
i think, but i didn't prepare "before" screensnaps to be sure.

This appears to be a global annoyance across more than one SE site (possibly all of them, I don't visit all of them.)

Comment: This is probably better off on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ since it's not specific to the DIY site.